# Submiting Symfony 2 embedded form with file using ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, file, symfony

I'm creating embedded file uploading form with file validation in Symfony 2. For file uploading I used this example http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html and for embedded forms this http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html. It's work perfect, but I must submit a form using ajax, how can I do it?

Below is a example how I submit form using ajax.

```
$("#submit_form").click(function() {

        var $form = $(this).parents('form:first');
        var $that = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function($data) {
                if ($data.status == 'ok') {
                    $that.parents('#lightbox').html($data.template);
                }
            },
            url: $form.attr('action')
        });

        return false;
    });
```

So the problem is I can't pass files with ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ . Works like a charm!

This can submit the form and also upload files. All you need to do is call ajaxSubmit and then implement the method that handles the response.

```
$('#myForm2').submit(function() { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({success: showResponse}); 
}); 

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 
    alert('status: ' + statusText + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + responseText + 
        '\n\nThe output div should have already been updated with the responseText.'); 
}
```